# Simplest of getJSON call not working

Tags: jquery, cross-browser, getjson

Can't seem to figure out what's wrong with the simple getJSON call below. It's working fine in FF12 but not in IE8 and Chrome19.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js">    </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$.getJSON('data.json',function(result){
    alert("success");
});
});
</script>
```

Please note that the following is working fine in all the browsers:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js">       </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
       alert("success");
});
</script>
```

So, apparently, something's wrong with the getJSON call.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

**Update:**
Thanks to samy.vilar I was able to get it working. Here are the things I corrected :-

1. Hosted the file to a server(IIS 7, in this case): To make an AJAX request the files got to be hosted on a server. I was trying to access data.json using the file system.
2. Added the MIME type for extension .json in IIS 7.

That did it. Though I still wonder how it was working in FF earlier when we can't complete an AJAX request without hosting.

Comment: Check the javascript console to see if you have an error when requesting your file.

Comment: what is the path of your "html file" and what is the path of your "json file"?

Comment: @Didier Ghys, No errors are being shown.

Comment: @Op De Cirkel, both are local files, i.e., not hosted anywhere.

Comment: how are you loading them? you need some kind of server, if you want to make ajax requests.

Comment: @samy.vilar: Thanks for the tip. So I hosted them locally but now it has stopped working in FF also. What do I mention for URL if data.json is located at http://localhost/demos/data.json?

Comment: you can either state the full url /demos/data.json or the relative data.json depending where this html file is and the root if your web server but to be honest its always good to use full paths to be safe.

Comment: Tried. Not working either way :-(. The html and json both are in the same directory.

Comment: if they are in the same directory then it should work, what kind of server are you running? you can try my example.

Comment: it just a try method, replace $ with jQuery. I have tried this once and this worked. Hope this may help you

Comment: @samy: Running IIS 6. Tried your example. Still no luck.

Comment: @Rohit: Thanks. But that didn't work either.

Comment: ok so that means you are on a windows platform probably using IIS6 or 7, first we need to very that IIS is working/configured properly, assuming your are running on port 80, modify test.html and simply some text outside the script, then go to `http://localhost/demos/test.html` and check if you see that text or look at the source of the html, that the browser receives. you can also check that the json file is properly being sent `http://localhost/demos/data.json` im assuming demos is the root, as configured in IIS.

Comment: Sorry, it's IIS 7. Tried your suggestions. Can see the modified test.html with plain text. So, guess the browser is configured fine. However, when i try to access http://localhost/demos/data.json I am getting the 403.14 forbidden error - "The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory". Could that be denying the access to .json?

Comment: finally, yeah IIS doesn't support json by default you have to `Open the properties for the server in IIS Manager and click MIME Types
Click "New".` `Enter "JSON" for the extension and "application/json" for the MIME type.`

Comment: or you can just rename the file to data.html it really doesn't matter ... getJSON will automatically evaluate the file, but you need to `$.getJSON('data.html', ...` if you do decide to rename it.

Comment: ok it should be good now, thank you, and good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since IIS doesn't support json by default you can try renaming the data.json to data.html this way IIS won't complain ;) ... just update getJSON to `$.getJSON('data.html,...`

if you want to enable .json file extension simply follow this instructions.
`Open the properties for the server in IIS Manager and click MIME Types`
`Click "New". Enter "JSON" for the extension and "application/json" for the MIME type.`

Comment: That worked!!! Really appreciate the help. Thanks :-). Though I still wonder how it was working in FF earlier when we can't complete an AJAX request without hosting?

Comment: Fundamentally ajax requests must be made using the same domain, if you make an ajax request to a different site it will complain, why? its a security feature, to prevent people from injecting malicious javascript code into your site, FireFox apparently just looks at URL if its the same prefix, no problem, google chrome goes a step further and verifies its origin and the domain matches, `file:///...` isn't a site and so its origin is `NULL`, rejects with something likes this `XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///path/to/your/data.html. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.`

Comment: if you still want to test it locally go to chrome.exe, right click, go to properties and append  --allow-file-access-from-files to executable path.

Answer (score 0):

This is the same problem with D3.js loading json data local.

The patches for D3.js can be found here:

https://github.com/jasondavies/d3/commit/95b1eaaf68a1e75e6cf95b88d7e4bbc834b8489d

The patches being applied makes local json data working.

I hope that these patches can be applied as well to jquery-1.7.2

I got same problem with jQtouch b4 which uses jQuery-1.7.2. Previous version of jQTouch b1 that uses jQuery-1.3.2 works fine.

Answer (score 0):

How to follow the following instructions in ubuntu ?
Open the properties for the server in IIS Manager and click MIME Types
Click "New". Enter "JSON" for the extension and "application/json" for the MIME type.